Tmux prefix doesn't work unless ~/.tmux.conf is forced
I'm currently including tmux into my work flow but I've not been able to use its prefix like it is set up natively C-b on start. My work around to this problem is to set another key bind on the following ~/.tmux.conf and force loading it with tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf.
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-t

.bashrc
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
eval "$(oh-my-posh init bash --config ~/.poshthemes/pure.omp.json)"

set -o vi

I've already checked bash vi mode isn't conflicting tmux
My work environment is:

Wsl 2 - Arch linux
Alacritty terminal run from windows

I'm a new user so please let me know if you need me to provide further details with a command or settings.

There a lots of answers in other forums that solved non-Arch linux users similar problem. After reading the Arch linux tmux wiki entry, I found that tmux config file must be placed somewhere else.
By default, tmux looks for user-specific configuration at $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/tmux/tmux.conf followed by ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf, as of 3.2. A global configuration file may be provided at /etc/tmux.conf though by default Arch does not ship such a file.
Taken from Arch tmux wiki entry

I found that tmux config file must be placed somewhere else False. Neither upstream tmux nor (upstream) Arch has removed ~/.tmux.conf from the search path list (AFAICT, not ever). Let alone the fact that it works in my installation as well. Maybe strace can help in telling you what actually went wrong in yours.

I'd like to find out what the problem is based on your suggestion but I'm a linux user with little experience. Could you expand your idea on using strace please? I had a look at it but couldn't figure out how to use it.
